# fs.readFileSync doesn't recognize file

Tags: node.js, fs

The fs.readFileSync function does not recognize the HTML-file, even tho it is localted in the same folder. The error says: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node.html'

```
const http = require('http');
const PORT = 3000;
const fs = require('fs')

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    if (req.url === '/') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
        const homePageHTML = fs.readFileSync('node.html');
        console.log(homePageHTML)
        res.end()
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
        res.write('<h1>Sorry, you were misled!</h1>')
        res.end()
    }
})

server.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear, it's unable to find that file in the current working directory. You should check the current working directory and adjust the path to `node.html`

Comment: solved It by changing the path to `${__dirname}\\node.html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical explanation for your issue is that when you start your program the current working directory in the OS is not the directory that contains your `node.html` file.  Thus, `fs.readFileSync('node.html', "utf8");` which only looks in the current working directory does not find the target file.

As you discovered, you can fix the problem by building a more complete path that specifies that actual directory you want, not just  the plain filename.  You could also make sure that the current working directory was set properly to your server directory before you started your app.

The usual way to build your own path to your server directory is by using `path.join()`:

```
fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'node.html'), "utf8");
```

Comment: I didn't know about path.join(). But I'll start using it. Seems like it's working on multiple OSs. :) Thank you.

Comment: @nichtverfügbar - The nice thing about `path.join()` is that it automatically inserts one and only one path separator between the pieces you have, regardless of whether each piece already had one or not and it uses the appropriate separator for the OS.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps me in my work-related projects. I struggle a lot with the appropriate seperation of Win and Linux. :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved It by changing the path to ${__dirname}\node.html.
Somehow needs the actual path. Which doesn't seems to be the case in the tutorial I'm watching.

Comment: Means you didn't start the app from the same dir the HTML is in.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes trying a basic npm reinstall can help:

```
npm install
```

I also noticed another problem when trying to reproduce your problem. You didn't specify and encoding type in your `fs.ReadFileSync` method, so the `console.log` outputted a buffer rather than a string. changing your `homePageHTML` string line into this should work

```js
const homePageHTML = fs.readFileSync('node.html', "utf8");
```

Let me know if this works or if you have any other problems.

Comment: Nope doesn't work. but I've tried. But I solved it my providing the whole path to the file.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, My code worked without needing to specify my whole path. Glad you found your problem!